# JQuery - Custom size in input[type=file] with CsTransPie

Tags: jquery, file-io

How to custom size the input:file using [CsTransPie](http://www.pkoretic.net/csTransPie/file.html)?

tried, but no luck:

```
$("#SomeID").css('width','470px');
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Raminson tried: `$('#SomeID').attr('style', 'width: 470px !important');` with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the width of the element that CTP creates.

```
$("#SomeID").closest("span").find(".cTPFileInput").css("width","470px");
```